# Pyodbc error with ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server. Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, docker, dockerfile

I have a Python application that connects to a SQL Server database using pyodbc and ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server. The application has been working fine for 4 months until last week, when I started getting this error:

```
ERROR:root:Error connecting to the database: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL
 Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have not changed anything in the code or the configuration of the server or the database.

This is the dockerfile I use to build the image for the application:

```
FROM python:3.8
# Update the system and install the necessary dependencies

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl gnupg

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
# Download and install the ODBC packages and other dependencies

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 mssql-tools unixodbc-dev libgssapi-krb5-2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*



RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install gcc \
  && apt-get -y install g++ \
  && apt-get -y install unixodbc unixodbc-dev \
  && apt-get clean

RUN  ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18

RUN export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"

RUN sed -i "s|TLSv1.2|TLSv1.0|g" /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

And this is the code I use to connect to the database:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
            'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};TrustServerCertificate=yes;SERVER=' + server +
';DATABASE=' + db + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password+ ';ENCRYPT=no',
            autocommit=True)
```

I have tried installing the OpenSSL 1.1.1 version as I have seen in other posts. There is also a companion that both the connection and the dockerfile have the same, just change the python version to 3.11. The problem is that due to libraries I need to continue using 3.8 as it has worked until now

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error and how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I need to connect to the database

Comment: Aside... the warnings in the Dockerfile build like `Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))` have been warnings since Debian 9 (python:3.8 builds on Debian 12) and are as good as errors for some packages now. Consider moving to `gpg --dermor` as soon as possible.